# Как можно создать систему компонентов, похожую на unity(Start,Update пр.)

Tags: c#, update, компоненты

В качестве практики пишу игровой движок, столкнулся с проблемой. Хотелось бы добавить возможность создавать компоненты, о которых изначально программа и не могла знать, но в конечном образе из-за наследования одного основного класса могла запустить метод "Start" или "Update". Для наглядности вот что хотелось бы сделать:

```
using ...;

public class ObjectBehavior
{

    public virtual void Start() 
    { 
    // Для каждого класса, наследующего этот класс запускать метод Start, при условии, что он там прописан. (они разные и про них ничего заранее программа не знает) 
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
     // Для каждого класса, наследующего этот класс запускать метод Update, при условии, что он там прописан.
    }
}

// другой файл

public class CameraController : ObjectBehavior
{
    public void Update()
    {
         // Внезапный метод Update во внезапном классе CameraController, наследующий OB.

         // Метода Start здесь нет, он не должен запускаться из OB.
    }
}
```

Comment: В CameraContoller метод `public void Update()` скрывает унаследованный метод. Студия должна подчёркивать его зелёным и компилятор предупреждение выдавать. Вы именно скрыть его хотите (тогда добавьте `new`) или просто ошиблись (тогда добавьте `override`)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov просто хочется, чтобы не надо было создавать каждый раз отдельно экземпляр для каждого из класса и из него запускать метод каждого из класса, а чтобы это делал основной класс для всех других. Надеюсь понятно изложил.

Comment: Нет, непонятно. PS: если в родительском классе в методах будет код, то и в дочерних классах этот код будет выполняться при вызове этих методов (если они не переопределены и не скрыты).

Comment: Я как раз хочу сделать обратно. Чтобы код дочерних объектов исполнялся в родительском. Объявил родительский класс, запускаю update для род. класса и update запускается и у всех дочерних(не base.Update(), а внутренний код дочерних). Хотя вроде пришла идея, можно это на ивентах переписать.

Comment: Это стандартный полиморфизм. Используйте `override`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае можно создать функцию Instantiate или Create и в ней в лист экземпляров будет записываться экземпляр класса(мы его можем закастить в класс ObjectBehavior), затем при Update циклом проходится по листу и запускать в нём функцию start или update.

```
public static void Instantiate(ObjectBehavior behavior)
{
   behaviors.Add(behavior);
}

public void SomeVoidInSomeClass()
{
   // Работает только в случае, если класс наследуется от ObjectBehavior
   ObjectBehavior.Instantiate((ObjectBehavior)this);
}
```